# Get page of selected item in kendo grid

Tags: javascript, kendo-ui, kendo-grid

I have a kendo grid where I preselect one item that can be on any page. In many cases, my default selected item is not on page one (which is usually the first page you see), so the selected item is hidden. I need to get the page number of the data item. How can I do this? Is there a function that I've not seen yet from kendo?

Comment: what criterium do you use for the order? maybe you can use that and pageSize to guess the page?

Comment: They aren't sorted or filtered in any way.

Comment: and is pagination done server or client side? If pagination is done server side, I don't think you have a way to know in which page your item is

Comment: It's done client side.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I remember, you can do something like that:

```
var index = dataSource.indexOf(item) + 1; // find where item is in data source

var pageSize = dataSource.pageSize(); // find how many items per page

var currentPage = Math.ceil(index/pageSize); // find at which page item is

dataSource.query({ page: currentPage, pageSize: dataSource.pageSize() }); // go to that page
```

[.pageSize()](http://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/api/javascript/data/datasource#methods-pageSize), [.query()](http://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/api/javascript/data/datasource#methods-query)